# Make Emacs ignore changes to file on disk

Tags: windows, linux, emacs

I'm using andLinux and for whatever reason, emacs seems to think that the file I'm editing has been changed every time I try to edit/save and keeps reprompting me. Very annoying. Is there a way to make emacs stop checking the file on the disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284703/emacs-how-to-disable-file-changed-on-disk-checking/2284921#2284921) to the SO question [Emacs: how to disable ‘file changed on disk’ checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284703/emacs-how-to-disable-file-changed-on-disk-checking) which basically says to add this to your .emacs:

```
(defun ask-user-about-supersession-threat (fn)
  "blatantly ignore files that changed on disk"
  )
```

Though this seems dangerous to do...